# Having to refresh page twice to see changes when using revalidate in Next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am making the following rest call to populate data on my page:

```
// src/app/page.js
const Home = async () => {
  const globalData = await getGlobalData();
  return (
    <main'>
      <SomeComponent data={globalData} />
    </main>
  );
};
```

The data is coming from a database and I know that the information has updated in DB since yesterday.

When the page loads, it is still showing old data. I have to refresh the page twice,

(Always twice) after which it reflects the new data.

Why do I not see the latest data immediately?

From now on, I will see new data every time the page loads. If data changes in DB hours ago, again, need to refresh twice to see.

P.S: I am using Next.js version `13.4.13`.

This is the logic where I have set it to refresh every 60 seconds. But as said, data was updated in db yesterday.

```
export const refresh = (seconds = 60) => ({ next: { revalidate: seconds }});

export const getGlobalData = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(`${myDomain}/api/global`, refresh());
    if (!res.ok) {
      console.log('Failed');
      return {};
    }
    return await res.json();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Connection refused`);
  }
  return {};
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when you set a `revalidate: 60`, Next.js won't update the cache every 60 even if there is no request made by a client. [Here is how it works](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/caching#time-based-revalidation):

> - The first time a fetch request with `revalidate` is called, the data will be fetched from the external data source and stored in the Data Cache.
> - Any requests that are called within the specified timeframe (e.g. 60-seconds) will return the cached data.
> - After the timeframe, the next request will still return the cached (now stale) data.
> - - Next.js will trigger a revalidation of the data in the background.
> - - Once the data is fetched successfully, Next.js will update the Data Cache with the fresh data.
> - - If the background revalidation fails, the previous data will be kept unaltered.
>
> This is similar to [stale-while-revalidate](https://web.dev/stale-while-revalidate/) behavior.

[image]

Comment: What's the normal approach here typically. Leave it as is or force some form of refresh on the page regularly to keep it updated. In my case, I have a time stamp on my page which indicates the last time a batch was done. Even though clearly the batch run was done more recently, it reflects a date from 24 hours back until I dual refresh.

Comment: Are you trying to have something automatically synced with your DB changes, without even refreshing? If so, you may want to look at websockets. But if only the two times things is bothering you, you can use `cache:no-store` to not have any cache.